# M2Crypto SSL and compression method

Tags: ssl, compression, m2crypto

How to set compression method for SSL/TLS connection created with M2Crypto and TwistedProtocolWrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build openssl with zlib support and select SSL context to use tlsv1 method solve the problem

M2Crypto.SSL.Context('tlsv1')